# Word for throwing an object away to get rid of bad memories

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or something to describe the act of throwing a physical object to get rid of bad memories or associated thoughts?

Comment: I can't think of them offhand, but I believe there are some metaphors involving cleaning that are used.

Comment: *purge*? “rid (someone or something) of an unwanted quality, condition, or feeling”

Comment: Ritual purification? Depends if it's some sort of magical ritual, or just trying to get rid of an unwelcome reminder.

Answer (score 1):

***Catharsis*** is a general term for the purging or release of negative thoughts and emotions, and is often accompanied by some physical or mental event. It doesn't refer to the specific act of throwing an item away, but throwing away an item which holds negative associations in order to achieve a mental release would be perfectly described as a cathartic act.

Answer (score 0):

I think the psycological concept of ***[repression](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repression)*** may convey the idea:

> a mental process by which distressing thoughts, memories, or impulses that may give rise to anxiety are excluded from consciousness and left to operate in the unconscious.

(M-W)

Comment: It seems to me that we're talking about painful memories that the sufferer is conscious of, and is trying to address, which doesn't line up too well with the provided definition of repression.

Answer (score 0):

"[Discard](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discard)"

> **to get rid of especially as useless or unwanted**

"[Purge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/purge)"

> **to make free of something unwanted**